# Add, Remove and Calculate Value and Price from Multiple Dropdowns

Tags: javascript

I am trying to practice similar thing like [here](https://www.booking.com/hotel/us/holiday-inn-new-york-city-midtown-57th-street.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaBKIAQGYATG4AQfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKoAgM;sid=1b1700e02123140755012bbd73b24e9e;all_sr_blocks=18176901_94324402_0_2_0;checkin=2017-02-16;checkout=2017-02-28;dest_id=20088325;dest_type=city;dist=0;highlighted_blocks=18176901_94324402_0_2_0;hpos=4;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srfid=2b571321d118d9496d5b95919816d596ec9c877fX4;type=total;ucfs=1&;selected_currency=USD;changed_currency=1#availability). `<option>` values represent room quantity, and texts represent their price. What I want to do is when I select a value even I selected another value before, the code should update the values and calculate prices. Same thing is also for removing.

How can I add, remove the values and calculate the price

https://jsfiddle.net/nsp0u703/

```js
function update(_this) {
 document.getElementById("booking_summary").style.display = "block";
 
 var textStr = _this.options[_this.selectedIndex].text;
 var startPos = textStr.indexOf("(") + 1;
 var endPos = textStr.indexOf(')',startPos);
 var priceWCurrency = textStr.substring(startPos, endPos);
 
 var setShowQuantity = document.querySelector("#booking_summary .squantity");
 setShowQuantity.innerHTML = _this.options[_this.selectedIndex].value;
 
 var roomSelectedText = document.querySelector("#booking_summary .rooms-count");
 var totalPrice = document.getElementById("total_price");
 
 var checkQuantity = setShowQuantity.innerHTML;
 if(checkQuantity == 0) {
  checkQuantity.innerHTML = "";
  roomSelectedText.innerHTML = "";
  totalPrice.innerHTML = "";
  return;
 } else {
  if(checkQuantity == 1 && checkQuantity != 0) {
   roomSelectedText.innerHTML = "room for";
  }
  if(checkQuantity > 1) {
   roomSelectedText.innerHTML = "rooms selected";
  }
  totalPrice.innerHTML = priceWCurrency;
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- first dropdown menu -->
<select onchange="update(this)">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1 (BAM 99)</option>
  <option value="2">2 (BAM 198)</option>
  <option value="3">3 (BAM 297)</option>
  <option value="4">4 (BAM 396)</option>
  <option value="5">5 (BAM 495)</option>
</select>
<br />
<!-- second dropdown menu -->
<select onchange="update(this)">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1 (BAM 99)</option>
  <option value="2">2 (BAM 198)</option>
  <option value="3">3 (BAM 297)</option>
  <option value="4">4 (BAM 396)</option>
  <option value="5">5 (BAM 495)</option>
</select>
<br />
<!-- third dropdown menu -->
<select onchange="update(this)">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1 (BAM 99)</option>
  <option value="2">2 (BAM 198)</option>
  <option value="3">3 (BAM 297)</option>
  <option value="4">4 (BAM 396)</option>
  <option value="5">5 (BAM 495)</option>
</select>
<br />
<!-- fourth dropdown menu -->
<select onchange="update(this)">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1 (BAM 99)</option>
  <option value="2">2 (BAM 198)</option>
  <option value="3">3 (BAM 297)</option>
  <option value="4">4 (BAM 396)</option>
  <option value="5">5 (BAM 495)</option>
</select>
<!-- display -->
    <div id="booking_summary">
      <strong class="squantity"></strong>
      <span class="rooms-count"></span> <br />
      <span id="total_price" class="total-price"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On change you should recalculate all selects. I've added some class and attribute for data-extraction reducing:

```js
function update() {
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll(".rooms");
  var roomsCount = 0;
  var priceTotal = 0;
  selects.forEach(function(select) {
    var roomsOfType = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if(roomsOfType != 0) {
      roomsCount += parseInt(roomsOfType);
      priceTotal += parseFloat(select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price"));
    }
  });
  var setShowQuantity = document.querySelector("#booking_summary .squantity");
  var roomSelectedText = document.querySelector("#booking_summary .rooms-count");
  var totalPrice = document.getElementById("total_price");
  
  if(roomsCount > 0) {
    document.getElementById("booking_summary").style.display = "block";
    totalPrice.innerText = priceTotal;
    setShowQuantity.innerText = roomsCount;
    roomSelectedText.innerText = roomsCount == 1 ? "room for" : "rooms selected";
  } else {
    totalPrice.innerText = "";
    setShowQuantity.innerText = "";
    roomSelectedText.innerText = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- first dropdown menu -->
Room type A:<select class="rooms" onchange="update()">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1" data-price="99">1 (BAM 99)</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="198">2 (BAM 198)</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="297">3 (BAM 297)</option>
  <option value="4" data-price="396">4 (BAM 396)</option>
  <option value="5" data-price="495">5 (BAM 495)</option>
</select>
<br />
<!-- second dropdown menu -->
Room type B:<select class="rooms" onchange="update()">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1" data-price="10">1 (BAM 10)</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="19">2 (BAM 19)</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="28">3 (BAM 28)</option>
  <option value="4" data-price="37">4 (BAM 37)</option>
  <option value="5" data-price="46">5 (BAM 46)</option>
</select>
<br />
<!-- third dropdown menu -->
Room type C:<select class="rooms" onchange="update()">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1" data-price="12">1 (BAM 12)</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="23">2 (BAM 23)</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="34">3 (BAM 34)</option>
  <option value="4" data-price="45">4 (BAM 45)</option>
  <option value="5" data-price="56">5 (BAM 56)</option>
</select>
<br />
<!-- fourth dropdown menu -->
Room type D:<select class="rooms" onchange="update()">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1" data-price="99">1 (BAM 99)</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="198">2 (BAM 198)</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="297">3 (BAM 297)</option>
  <option value="4" data-price="396">4 (BAM 396)</option>
  <option value="5" data-price="495">5 (BAM 495)</option>
</select>
<!-- display -->
    <div id="booking_summary">
      <strong class="squantity"></strong>
      <span class="rooms-count"></span> <br />
      <span id="total_price" class="total-price"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are my hero for today! Seems like I have some unnecessary codes.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything in a `<form>` then register the change event on it. Any form node within `<form>` that has a `[name]` attribute can easily be accessed. Using the `for` attribute on the `<output>` makes them associated with the designated `<select>`s.

**SNIPPET**

```css
select,
option {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<form id='booking' name='booking' onchange='qty.value = Number(s1.value) + Number(s2.value) + Number(s3.value) + Number(s4.value); total.value=(qty.value * 99)'>

  <!-- first dropdown menu -->
  <label for='s1'>Lot 1</label>
  <select id='s1' name='s1'>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1 - $99</option>
    <option value="2">2 - $198</option>
    <option value="3">3 - $297</option>
    <option value="4">4 - $396</option>
    <option value="5">5 - $495</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <!-- second dropdown menu -->
  <label for='s2'>Lot 2</label>
  <select id='s2' name='s2'>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1 - $99</option>
    <option value="2">2 - $198</option>
    <option value="3">3 - $297</option>
    <option value="4">4 - $396</option>
    <option value="5">5 - $495</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <!-- third dropdown menu -->
  <label for='s3'>Lot 3</label>
  <select id='s3' name='s3'>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1 - $99</option>
    <option value="2">2 - $198</option>
    <option value="3">3 - $297</option>
    <option value="4">4 - $396</option>
    <option value="5">5 - $495</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <!-- fourth dropdown menu -->
  <label for='s4'>Lot 4</label>
  <select id='s4' name='s4'>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1 - $99</option>
    <option value="2">2 - $198</option>
    <option value="3">3 - $297</option>
    <option value="4">4 - $396</option>
    <option value="5">5 - $495</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/>
  <!-- display -->
  <fieldset id="summary">
    <legend>Summary</legend>
    <label for='qty'>Rooms:</label>
    <output for='s1 s2 s3 s4' id='qty' name='qty'></output>
    <label for='total'>Total: $</label>
    <output for='qty' id="total" name='total'></output>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```